# Excluding Time Segment from Bootstrap Date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Datetime picker; Below is the link;

https://fiddle.jshell.net/0sowpm1v/2/

Question 1:
Currently the picker is showing Time as 00:00 even if user is not selecting the time component.
What I am trying to achieve is, If user is not selecting any time then time segment will drop.

If user selects the date as '2015-05-01' then output should be '2015-05-01' instead of '2015-05-01 00:00'.

Question 2:

If this is not possible Can we trigger any function call in 'onClose' event of the picker?

N.B : The concerned Datetime picker is not supporting the 'onClose' event and I am unaware of its equivalent method.

Below is my Code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control"  />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the JQuery binding of DateTime picker;

```
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                format : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
            });
```

Comment: I need TimeSegment, making format as 'YYYY-MM-DD' will drop Time Selection. If user is selecting time then I need to show it. So changing format is not gonna work.

Comment: You should have your code in question, not on external site.

Comment: It's a fiddle link. And I am trying to implement simple Bootstrap Date time picker, the code is not specific to my question. Anyways I will edit the question.

Comment: Yes, it is a fiddle link, and? It is suddenly no longer external site or what?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated the question. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
                    autoclose: true,
                });
```

Comment: I need TimeSegment, making format as 'YYYY-MM-DD' will drop Time Selection. If user is selecting time then I need to show it. So changing format is not gonna work.

Answer (score -1):

This is just an work around. If any one has better answer, You are welcome to share it.

This is the JQuery workaround that I have implemented.

```
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
                useStrict: true,
                keepInvalid: true
            });

            $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function(e) {
                if ($('#lblValue').text() == 1) {
                    $('#lblValue').text('2');
                    $('#txtDate').val('');
                } else if ($('#lblValue').text() == 2) {
                    $('#lblValue').text('3');
                }
            });

            $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.hide", function(e) {
                if ($('#lblValue').text() == 2 && $('#txtDate').val() == '') {
                    $('#lblValue').text('4');
                } else {
                    $('#lblValue').text('2');
                }

                if ($("#txtDate").val() != "" && $("#txtDate").val().trim().substring(16, 10).trim() == "00:00") {
                    $("#txtDate").val($("#txtDate").val().trim().substring(10, 0));
                }
            });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12316627)

Comment: As per my knowledge, fiddle link normally doesn't change. Correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: I'm just wondering how did you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) without code. Hopefully that's the reason your answer has not formatted. See [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) point no 5, because of that SO categorizing your answer as low quality post. Better to add your code with your demo link will be an appropriate answer.

Comment: I didn't say my fiddle doesn't have any code. I just asked whether fiddle link changes?? Any ways I have added the code. Further any help will be appreciated.